# How can I swap elements of a row with the same elements of another row in a table?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to make the data not real but still make sense in a way. For example,
the main table looks like:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | A |
| 2 | b | B |
| 3 | c | C |

And I want it to be like this after the transformation:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | b | C |
| 3 | a | B |
| 2 | c | A |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is your data stored - a list of lists, a pandas dataframe, something else?

Comment: it's originally an sql table but i probably will import it as pandas dataframe